# Is gen_tcp:send/2 blocking?

Tags: tcp, erlang

Is gen_tcp:send() asynchronous? Assume I'll send some byte array using gen_tcp:send/2. Will process continue to work:

a) Immediately
b) At the time data will arrive in target's inner buffer
c) When the target gets the data from buffer

Thank You in advance.

Comment: See discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448581/gen-tcp-send-non-blocking-in-erlang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gen_tcp:send/2` is synchronous. It means that the call returns only after the given packet is really sent. Usually it happens immediately, however if TCP window is full `gen_tcp:send/2` blocks until the data is sent. So it means that the call can theoretically block infinitely (for example when receiver does not read data from socket on its side). 
Fortunately there are some options to avoid such situation. There are two options `{send_timeout, Integer}` and `{send_timeout_close, Boolean}` for sockets which can be specified by the call `inet:setopts/2`. The first one allows to specify a longest time to wait for a send operation.

When the limit is exceeded, the  send operation will return `{error, timeout}`. Default value of that option is `infinity` (and it is the reason of infinite block). Also unfortunately it is unknown how much of data was sent if `{error, timeout}` was returned. In that case it is better to close the socket. If the second option `{send_timeout_close, Boolean}` is set to `true` then the socket will be close automatically if `{error, timeout}` occurs.

Comment: So in large scale server it's not a good idea to send data to all clients in foreach loop on one process. Right?

Comment: It would usually not necessarily be a good idea. Having separate processes for each connection is often simpler to maintain in the long run.

Comment: The better idea is to handle connections in separate processes (one process for each connection).